# covariance for measuring linear relationship, how about the non-linear relationship

Tags: correlation, mathematical-statistics, covariance

I once heard the statement that

```
Covariance is a measure of the linear relationship between two variables, such as X and Y
```

If X and Y has non-linear relationship, what will be the metric corresponding to Covariance

Comment: You can get some ideas here:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65829/can-pca-be-extended-to-account-for-nonlinear-dependencies,   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/218127/intuition-behind-pearson-correlation-co-variance-and-cosine-similarity/218158#218158   and    https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17618/what-can-i-do-beyond-pearson-correlation/50680#50680

Comment: It depends partly how general you want to be. Do you want to measure the strength of monotonic relationships? General functional relationships? Relations that are *not* functions (like $X^2+Y^2 = r^2$)? Completely general forms of dependence?